# Obtain the filtered keyframe screenshot from the video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to get keyframe images from the video;In order to get the main plot of the video;

I would like to restrict keyframe generation; For example, only one keyframe is taken every 7s or every 3s;

(In addition to generating all the key frame images. And then filter it based on pts time. Is there any other way?)

The following command can restrict pts to multiples of n(such as 7).

`ffmpeg -y  -i   15103.mp4    -vf "select='eq(pict_type,PICT_TYPE_I)*not(mod(n,7))'"  -vsync vfr -s 480x270 -frame_pts true p2/out-%d.png`

But it's still not quite what I need.    I need to get one keyframe if there are key frames in these seconds.  Or get zero keyframe if there is no keyframe in these seconds.

How do I modify the command?

`ffmpeg -y  -i   15103.mp4    -vf "select='eq(pict_type,PICT_TYPE_I)'"  -vsync vfr -s 480x270 -frame_pts true p2/out-%d.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict decoding to only keyframes, and then set select to require a minimum time interval between selections.

`ffmpeg -y -skip_frame nokey -i 15103.mp4 -vf "select='if(eq(n,0),1,gte(t-prev_selected_t,7))'" -vsync vfr -s 480x270 -frame_pts true p2/out-%d.png`

Comment: - Thank you for your help to solve my problem;I have one more question:
- If  add another requirement, use only one command to implement the following requirement:

1. Fix a screenshot every 10 seconds.
2. The key frame problem described above.

- Can we optimize this command?(video is 25 fps)
  `ffmpeg -y  -i   15103.mp4   
   -vf  "select='(gte(n,0))*not(mod(n,250))'" -vsync vfr -s 480x270   p5/out-%d.png 
   -vf "select='eq(pict_type,PICT_TYPE_I)*if(eq(n,0),1,gte(t-prev_selected_t,7))'"  -vsync vfr -s 480x270 -frame_pts true p6/out-%d.png`  
  @Gyan